Asymptotic behaviour of number of isomeric $n-$ alkanes
I wonder about the asymptotic behaviour of the integer sequence discussed in this question. As answered there OEIS has the sequence on hand, and the linearlity of logarithmic scatterplot there strongly suggests that it has exponential growth, but the precise exponent (seems to be about $\sqrt e$ since the slope is nearly $1/2$) is unknown to me. Plenty of references are given there but I don't know which one to read for the answer. Please give some advice if you know it. Thanks!

Using the first 1000 terms (https://oeis.org/A000602/b000602.txt) makes me think that the base is closer to $e$ than $\sqrt e$. Mathematica suggests a base for the exponent of about $2.7934$.

Look at pg 478 of this book:
https://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf
I think it has what you are looking for.
